# Two sample differences between percentage means with negative percentages

Tags: t-test, mean

Hello to everyone and thank you for all the help you've already unknowingly provided to me in the past.

I have a group of percentages around zero that are grouped into two categories, and I wanted to know if using a two sample t-test would be appropriate.  Both positive and negative values exist, and the values can exceed 100% and -100%, though none of them do by more ~50%.  My interest isn't whether the mean is close to zero, but simply if the two groups differ significantly.  The data exhibits gaussian distribution, but the mean is not about zero, roughly being -27%.

Would there be any problem using a two sample t-test here?  I wouldn't assume so, but I haven't worked statistically with percentages, or negative percentages very much, and I just want to make sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the two groupings differ significantly"? Are you trying to compare their means, or the entire distributions, or perhaps something else?

Comment: Great question...  The distributions appear slightly different, but I'm not really interested in that.  I'm more interested in whether the means of the two groups is significantly different, which is why I was thinking a simple t-test.  I'm just not sure if it's ok to use that method with percentages, and also negative percentages...